# SalesForce, "Add more" Link to add new fields on the fly

Tags: salesforce

I have created an opportunity page layout in SalesForce.com and it is working fine. I have a situation where I need to add Airline information. I have created three fields and added these to the opportunity one by one; the HTML look like this:

```
<p>
     <label>
        <span>Airline 1:</span>
        <span style="margin-left: 120px;">Airline 2:</span>
        <span style="margin-left: 120px;">Airline 3:</span>
     </label><br>
     <input type="text" style="width: 150px;" class="text small" id="txtAirline" value="" name="txtAirline">
     <input type="text" style="width: 150px;" class="text small" id="txtAirline2" value="" name="txtAirline2">
     <input type="text" style="width: 150px;" class="text small" id="txtAirline3" value="" name="txtAirline3">
</p>

<p>
      <label>
          <span>PNR 1:</span>
          <span style="margin-left: 130px;">PNR 2:</span>
          <span style="margin-left: 130px;">PNR 3:</span>
      </label><br>
      <input type="text" style="width: 150px;" class="text small" id="txtPnr" value="" name="txtPnr">
      <input type="text" style="width: 150px;" class="text small" id="txtPnr2" value="" name="txtPnr2">
      <input type="text" style="width: 150px;" class="text small" id="txtPnr3" value="" name="txtPnr3">
</p>
```

Now, instead of adding filed for Airline and PNR again and again, I would like to add an "Add more" link which would create a clone of both fields and add it below one by one.

Is this possible?

Comment: your source has no apparent binding to salesforce controller so it doesnt even look like a vf page. How did you inject html into page layout and how is this working at all?

Comment: @mmix thanks for your reply, this is just an overview of how it is looking, i have just added custom fields and then add those to fields opportunity page layout, i have simply follow steps to add customs fields to opportunity page layout

Comment: The source is useless in that form, so it should be removed. Ant to answer your question, there is no way to dynamically control the flow of information in factory layouts (thats why we have vforce).

Comment: thanks @mmix, i will take care in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem will be with binding. It would be fairly easy to write some Javascript that would do exactly what you want when they click a button but how will that data get back to the controller?

Perhaps you can try the following:

Create a custom object for the airline information. It can have whatever info you need. It will need to be tied to the Opportunity object via a relationship field (perhaps a Master-Detail type). In your opportunity you can then add a related list of airline information. MAke sure you add the airline info as part of the Layout. SFDC will handle most of the UI for you at that point - so it won't look exactly as you have it set up - but it will do what you want to do.

Comment: ryan, thanks for your reply, this is what i did exactly, created a custom object for Airline then created a Master-Detail and added related list in opportunity for same, but related list goes to the bottom of the page layout, but i want to add Airline info in the Flight Info section not as a separate section

Comment: SFDC is kind of a pain that way. You can play with the layout a little but to get exactly what you want you may have to write your own custom page in VisualForce, so you'll have to consider how bad you really want it set up like that.

Answer (score 0):

I would handle this in the way that Ryan Describes, Create a custom object called "Airline" or something along those lines, create extra fields if required and add a lookup to Opportunity, this will create a related list on Opportunity which you can customize to show the fields that you require.

I assume that PNR is Passenger Name Record and you are recording passenger names, not sure if you can put this on the same airline object or if you need another object. You also might want to consider using Leads.